# What JPA 2.0 ORM currently implements the JPA 2.0 specification most correctly and with the least bugs?

Tags: java, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0

For anyone who has experience using several ORMs, please, illuminate me with respect to the the title.

I am currently implementing a tool that relies on the JPA 2.0 MetaModel API in order to serve its purpose.  In order to test this tool, I have created a test model that implements as many different mappings as I can think of.

What I've found, bouncing between EclipseLink 2.x and Hibernate 4.x, is that BOTH ORM's have some pretty serious bugs that require either a non-compliant workaround or undesirable changes to the database schema.

For example, Hibernate will not update the order column on bidirectional one-to-many relationships when using the 'mappedBy' attribute.

EclipseLink, on the other hand, won't work with join columns on one-to-many relationships  if the join column is constrained as 'not null' in the database, forcing you to remove the not-null constraint (buh-bye data integrity)

These particular issues already have issue tickets created for their respective ORMs, but are only a sampling of the problems I have encountered.

Before I go randomly trying other ORMs that allow me to build my test cases, can anyone recommend an ORM with no severe specification related bugs? I realize, of course, that 'no bugs at all' is a ridiculous pipe dream, I am specifically trying to avoid bugs that result in being unable to use what should be a JPA 2.0 compliant mapping without making serious database design concessions (i.e. requiring nullable foreign key references for dependent entities).

Thank you.

Comment: Simple way is just to look at the appropriate issue tracker for each of the main 4 implementations, look at the total number and the length of time some of the problems have been present. Obviously that would include things that your project doesn't need, so may not give the best answer for your project. Clearly if the JPA TCK was available for all to see (which it isn't) and contribute to (which it isn't either) then it would be a simple process of validating compliance.

Comment: I initially started looking at issue tracking (btw, eclipselink...lets get with the times) across projects, but it was immediately clear that it would be difficult to determine which bugs affect JPA 2.0 compliance either directly or indirectly when you take into account the hundreds upon hundreds of issues to look at (not mention following issue links to other issues etc.).  The task is just too daunting, hence the appeal to any experts that may be out and about.